# Using an object property as a function and as an object simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a way to declare an object property as a function, but also as an object, at the same time.

I have a JavaScript program that provides a simple API that sends AJAX requests to a server. My goal is trying to make this API as simple and human-readable as possible.

Basically, I'd like to make it possible to do this:

```
var app = new App();
app.get.client(123) // Get client ID 123
app.get.client.list() // Get an array of all clients
app.login('username', 'password') // Send credentials to log as username/password
app.login.as('John') // Login using credentials stored in a server-side constant
```

I doubt that's even possible as I've never anything like it, but I can't think of a more clear and human-readable way to lay out methods. Sure would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function’s an object too!

```
app.get.client = function(id) {
    // Get client by ID
};

app.get.client.list = function() {
    // List them
};
```

works as you’d expect.

---

Personally, though, I’d find:

```
app.clients.byId(123)
app.clients
app.login('username', 'password')
app.loginAs('John')
```

more readable.

Comment: What about making possible `app.get.client(123)` as well as `app.get.client(123).offers(456)`?

Comment: @RémiBreton: `app.get.client` just returns an object with an `offers` method.